# I need a regexp to parse in php a car license plate

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that can contain multiple car license plates. In Spain licence car plates are composed by four digits and three letters, but the user can separate them by an space or a hyphen. So I have this regular expresion to try to match all cases.

```
(\d{4})( *)(-*)( *)([a-zA-Z]{3})
```

So it acceps 1234 ABC or 1234ABC or 1234-ABC.

My problem is when a user inserts multiples car plates in same input text field. I can get values like 1234 ABC 4567BCX and I need to separate them in an array with one car license plate for each array position.
Here is the php code I'm trying but it does not work...

```
$matricula = "1234 ABC 2345 rBC";
$regexp1 = '/(\d{4})( *)(-*)( *)([a-zA-Z]{3})/';
$regexp2 = '/((\d{4})( *)(-*)( *)([a-zA-Z]{3})( )*)+/';
preg_match($regexp2,$matricula,$matches);
$result = array_shift($matches);
var_dump($matches);

var_dump(preg_split($regexp2, $matricula));
```

Can any body help me please?

Comment: not trying to change your requirements.. but just a polite suggestion.. wouldn't it be better if that string had a separation character for plates so that they would be easier to read when "serialized"? something like comma separated values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be an approach:

```
<?php
$input = "1234-ABC 2345 rBC 9998DDD 9657   lJi";
preg_match_all('/(\d{4}[-\s]*[a-z]{3})/i', $input, $matches);
$output = array_shift($matches);
array_walk($output, function(&$value) {
    $value = strtoupper(str_replace(" ", "", $value));
});
print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1234ABC
    [1] => 2345RBC
    [2] => 9998DDD
    [3] => 9657LJI
)
```

Comment: this solution ignores the optional dash in the input. And what if the user inputs an extra comma or slash between licenseplate numbes? Suggestion: before processing remove all non-word characters and non-digits from the input (even white spaces could be removed for Arkascha's script to work.)
preg_replace('/[^0-9A-Z]/', '', $input);

Comment: @IvoP Thanks for pointing out the hyphen, I fixed the pattern accordingly. About other characters: the question does not mention any such thing, so any attempt to do such thing is speculation and not an answer. If required at a later stage the solution certainly can be adapter accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You regular expression `(\d{4})( *)(-*)( *)([a-zA-Z]{3})` was correct but  you needed to use `preg_match_all` to return multiple matches.

This is a demo:

https://onlinephp.io/c/e5acb

```
<?php

function parsePlates($subject){
    $plates = [];
    preg_match_all('/(\d{4})( *)(-*)( *)([a-zA-Z]{3})/sim', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
        $plate = $result[0][$i];
        $plates[] = $plate;
    }
    return $plates;
}

$plates = parsePlates('1234 ABC 4567BCX');
var_dump($plates);
```